Is It OK to donate the meat of two sacrificial goats fully and to keep one?
If my father, my wife and myself conduct qurbani i.e. one goat qurabani per person, is it ok to distribute two out of those three goats in poor and needy and keep one goat for self. Rather than distributing two portions of each goat individually. Its just a semantics question. The intent is the same.

hanafi
According to the Hanafis it is permitted to eat all of the meat by oneself and it is also permitted to give it all away as a donations and gifts. It is recommended (not obligatory) to keep 1/3 for yourself, to use 1/3 for feeding friends and relatives and to give away 1/3 as donations to the poor.
Hence, according to this madhab what you are proposing is at least permissible.
Ref: Bada'i al-Sana'i
